# Can pkg install without dependencies in FreeBSD 10.3?

Tags: php, postgresql, freebsd

In FreeBSD 10.3, I'd like to install php 5.6 and postgresql 9.5 by `pkg install`. however, php56-pdo_pgsql depend postgresql-client-9.3, and install postgresql-client-9.5  after that will asked to remove php56-pdo_pgsql.

Is it possible to install php56-pdo_pgsql without postgresql-client-9.3?

Answer (score 1):

The general advise is to build the package yourself using the ports tree (see for example [this link on the FreeBSD forum](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/48765/#post-272490)).

However, I encountered this issue as well, and I just decided to take an easier step down into dependency hell (which was probably what the people behind 'pkg' were trying to prevent when they decided not to provide a '--nodeps' option...):

The .txz package file (you can download it via http://pkg.freebsd.org/freebsd:10:x86:64/latest/All/), is an xz-ipped tar file. So, you can unzip and untar it (on Windows, you can use 7-Zip, for example). The root directory of the archive contains two manifest files. These are regular text files, and contain, among other things, the list of dependencies. So, I just changed the dependencies in there from postgresql93 to postgresql95, and re-packaged the stuff. After that, I used 'pkg add' to install it without any issues.

Comment: `pkg add -M <filename>` allows installing a package file with missing dependencies. But you don't want to go there...

Comment: Did you bother with preserving absolute paths starting at `/`, or the default `./` (or no prefix at all) did the trick for you? I am having trouble installing the modified package, so wondering whether it is worth spending more time at finding how to create absolute paths with BSD tar.